# Highlighting a table row value

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, controller

I have the following piece of code.

```
<apex:repeat var="myPubA" value="{!Active.NoSharing.MyAuthorList}">
    <ul >
        <li onload="highlight(this,!myPubA.Pub__c)">{!myPubA.Pub__r.Pub_Title__c}</li>
    </ul>
</apex:repeat>

<script>
    function highlight(element, Id) {
        var pubid='{!PubId}';  //This value comes from the controller(from url)
        if (Id==pubid) {
            element.style = 'background-color: yellow';
        }
    }
    }
</script>
```

What I want to do is turn the value of the `<li>` tag yellow on load if the id passed in the url matches the value of the id in table. Only that value row is highlighted. Not any other rows Is this a feasible way of doing it? I am fairly new to both javascript and salesforce. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can highlight the row "on the fly" just using the `IF` statement:

```
<apex:repeat var="myPubA" value="{!Active.NoSharing.MyAuthorList}">
    <ul >
        <li style="{!IF(PubId == myPubA.Pub__c, 'background-color: yellow', '')}">{!myPubA.Pub__r.Pub_Title__c}</li>
    </ul>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: Can u tell me, if its possible to highlight just the value printed by {!myPubA.Pub__r.Pub_Title__c}. This code is highlighting the entire row of <li> tag @mast0r

Comment: @Rimii Yet it is possible like this: `<li><span style="{!IF(PubId == myPubA.Pub__c, 'background-color: yellow', '')}">{!myPubA.Pub__r.Pub_Title__c}</span></li>`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JS to do this you can do it in VF page easily with IF function as below.

`<li style="background-color:{!if(myPubA.Pub__c==PubId,'yellow','white')}">{!myPubA.Pub__r.Pub_Title__c}</li>`